# Pipelining String in Powershell

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell, ssh, pipeline

I'm trying to make a simple PowerShell function to have a Linux-style ssh command. Such as:

`ssh username@url`

I'm using plink to do this, and this is the function I have written:

```
function ssh {
    param($usernameAndServer)

    $myArray = $usernameAndServer.Split("@")

    $myArray[0] | C:\plink.exe -ssh $myArray[1]
}
```

If entered correctly by the user, $myArray[0] is the username and $myArray[1] is the URL. Thus, it connects to the URL and when you're prompted for a username, the username is streamed in using the pipeline. Everything works perfectly, except the pipeline keeps feeding the username ($myArray[0]) and it is entered as the password over and over. Example:

```
PS C:\Users\Mike> ssh xxxxx@yyyyy
login as: xxxxx@yyyyy's password:
Access denied
xxxxx@yyyyy's password:
Access denied
xxxxx@yyyyy's password:
Access denied
xxxxx@yyyyy's password:
Access denied
xxxxx@yyyy's password:
Access denied
xxxxx@yyyyy's password:
FATAL ERROR: Server sent disconnect message
type 2 (protocol error):
"Too many authentication failures for xxxxx"
```

Where the username has been substituted with xxxxx and the URL has been substituted with yyyyy.

Basically, I need to find out how to stop the script from piping in the username ($myArray[0]) after it has been entered once.

Any ideas? I've looked all over the internet for a solution and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doesn't plink allow you to specify the user and host together in one argument?  that is:

plink -ssh user@host

if so your ssh function could be whittled down to:

```
function ssh {
    param($usernameAndServer)

    C:\plink.exe -ssh $usernameAndServer
}
```